# Creating a Python list from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have, for example, a list of tuples such as

```
a = [(1,2)] * 4
```

how would I create a list of the first element of each tuple? That is, `[1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [(1,2)] * 4
>>> [t[0] for t in a]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You can also unpack the tuple:

```
>>> [first for first,second in a]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you want to get fancy, combine [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). In python 3, you'll have to wrap the construct in `list` to get a list instead of an iterable:

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(0), a)
<map object at 0x7f3971029290>
>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), a))
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: The tuple-unpacking option is fastest (on my Python 2.7, using a million-element list with no structure sharing in the tuples). The differences are quite small, though.

Answer (score 6):

Two alternatives to phihag's list comprehension:

```
[x for x, y in a]

from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter(0), a)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways:

```
>>> a = [(1,2)] * 4

>>> # List comprehension
>>> [x for x, y in a]
[1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> # Map and lambda
>>> map(lambda t: t[0], a)
[1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> # Map and itemgetter
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(0), a)
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The technique of using *map* fell out of favor when list comprehensions were introduced, but now it is making a comeback due to parallel map/reduce and multiprocessing techniques:

```
>>> # Multi-threading approach
>>> from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
>>> Pool(2).map(operator.itemgetter(0), a)
[1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> # Multiple processes approach
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> def first(t):
        return t[0]
>>> Pool(2).map(first, a)
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: +1 for the most over-engineered code to work on `[(1,2)] * 4`.

Comment: @phihag Never miss an opportunity to use simple examples as way to introduce a full range of Python capabilities :-)  I presume the OP will have more interesting datasets to work with ;-)

Comment: @Raymond Hettinger you are correct. In practice I have a list of over 2 million such tuples.

Comment: @user1475412 If they're indeed tuples, you won't get any performance advantage by using multiple threads or multiple processes, because the cost of calling `operator.itemgetter(0)` is minimal. A multithreaded approach is only useful if the operation you're applying on each element is slow.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger The last example fails on my system with a [rather curious error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235054/why-cant-i-use-operator-itemgetter-in-a-multiprocessing-pool).

Comment: @phihag I just fixed-it up to use a regular function definition.  The multiple process version needs everything to be pickleable.  Neither *itemgetter* nor *lambda* fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [(1,2)] * 4
first_els = [x[0] for x in a]
```

Comment: Don't use `tuple` as a variable name.  In particular don't use it as the name of a list!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of tuples:

```
lta = [(1,2), (2,3), (44,45), (37,38)]
```

access the first element of each tuple would involve subscripting with [0], and visiting each tuple to extract each first element would involve a a list comprehension, which can be assigned to a variable as shown below:

```
resultant_list = [element[0] for element in lta]
>>> resultant_list
[1, 2, 44, 37]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out about Python's `zip()` function. Another way to do what I want to do here is:

```
list( zip( *a )[0] )
```

`tup_list = zip( list1, list2 )` interleaves two lists into a list of 2-tuples, but `zip( *tup_list )` does the opposite, resulting in a list of a tuple of `list1` and a tuple of `list2`.