# python iteration through list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list a with below elements :

```
[[('433318', 0.7064461851335214), ('433363', 0.6709502341952089)],
 [('433395', 0.6988424611161282), ('433400', 0.6794787567547861)],
 [('433395', 0.6871546406771576), ('433363', 0.653218445986381)]]
```

Now I wanted retrieve the elements into a new list b which will have

['433318','433363','433395','433400','433395','433363']

```
a[0][0][0] gives ‘433318’
a[0][1][0] gives ‘433363’
```

But I am looking for a generic way (may be in a loop which iterates through the entire list) and gives me the desired result ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Python list from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231186/creating-a-python-list-from-a-list-of-tuples) and a _metric ton_ of other, related questions and solutions provided on SO...

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
l = [[('433318', 0.7064461851335214), ('433363', 0.6709502341952089)],
[('433395', 0.6988424611161282), ('433400', 0.6794787567547861)],
[('433395', 0.6871546406771576), ('433363', 0.653218445986381)]]

[y[0] for x in l for y in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using a list comprehension is best**, but it may be helpful to see how a regular loop version would look like:

```py
my_list = [[('433318', 0.7064461851335214), ('433363', 0.6709502341952089)],
[('433395', 0.6988424611161282), ('433400', 0.6794787567547861)],
[('433395', 0.6871546406771576), ('433363', 0.653218445986381)]]

result = []
for inner_list in my_list:
    for inner_tuple in inner_list:
        result.append(inner_tuple[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Federico to this loop explanation.